# Adapting this VBA code to counting duplicates in columns

Tags: excel, function, vba

I'm having trouble adapting this code to my situation. I would like to create a function that allows me to count the number of duplicates in a column (I believe it currently only counts for rows).
Many thanks!

```
Function CountPairs(rng As Variant) As Integer
Dim v As Variant
Dim count, length, i As Integer
Dim found As Boolean
count = 0
found = False
v = rng
length = UBound(v, 2)

 For i = 1 To length

' Count if second of pair

 If Not (IsEmpty(v(1, i))) Then
 If found Then
     count = count + 1
     found = False
 Else
     found = True
 End If
Else
 found = False
End If

Next i

CountPairs = count

End Function
```

Comment: This does not count duplicates but basically counts the number of non empty cells and returns half.  For example the array {1,2,3,4,5,6} would return 3 where it should return 0 if it were looking for duplicates.

Comment: @ScottCraner - the current function will return 2 for the array {1,2, ,3, ,4,5,6} but 3 for {1,2, ,3,4, ,5,6}, and 0 for {1, ,2, ,3, ,4, ,5, ,6}.  So it is actually counting the number of times that two consecutive non-empty cells exist.  (But **definitely** isn't counting duplicates!)

Comment: Thank you everyone, I used all your advice and things seem to work now :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you copy the range that you wish to count the duplicates to a new sheet, transpose it and then apply the `RemoveDuplicates` function - your number of duplicates would then be `Selection.Rows.Count - (WorksheetFunction.CountA (Selection)/Selection.Columns.Count))`

Comment: @ScottCraner I could be badly mistaken but I think you're wrong - It'd count the number of rows removed (ie. the number of duplicates. Incorporating you you solution above gives the number of unique values but you're right in saying it's less work so maybe something like `CountA("A1:A10") - SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10))`

Comment: Ah sorry you are correct I did not look close enough.

Comment: The formula in your comments passes a #Div0 error if there are blanks in the range. as it returns a 0 when it gets to the empty space. Other than that it works great.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too - I can't think of a work around on that though so maybe the transposing method would be best? @ScottCraner

Comment: The more I think about it though, both those methods would count if there is more than two, triplicates will count as two, again this may be something the OP wants, so it is just a note.

Comment: `Setection` ?!?!? (Typo for `Selection` perhaps?  ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

The following Array formula will count duplicates:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A1:A13,A1:A13)=2,1/COUNTIF(A1:A13,A1:A13)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

If you want to count any multiple, triplicates and so forth as 1 then:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A1:A13,A1:A13)>1,1/COUNTIF(A1:A13,A1:A13)))
```

If you only want to count the unique non empty cells then:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A13<>"",1/COUNTIF(A1:A13,A1:A13)))
```